# How to find biholomorphisms between two simply connected domains of $\mathbb{C} $

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

We know that any two simply connected subsets of $\mathbb{C} $ (which neither of them is $\mathbb{C} $), are biholomorphic. I wonder if there's a good way of finding explicit functions.

For example - how can I find biholomorphism between the upper half plain and the quadrant $ \left\{ z=u+iv|u>0,v>0\right\}  $

I'd really appreciate an explanation of how to start thinking about it and defining the biholomirphisms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quadrant to half plane is easy: $z\mapsto z^2.$

Comment: There are a few elementary biholomorphisms which one should keep handy: Multiplication by a complex number dilates and rotates. Roots and powers contract or fan out slices. Möbius transformations can transform half planes to discs and vice versa. $\exp$ transforms strips to slit discs and $\log$ does the opposite.

Comment: Usually, if you are given two simply connected subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, you can either use one of the biholomorphic maps as in @Vercassivelaunos's comment, or more generally a composition of several of these maps. For instance, if you want to map the first quadrant biholomorphically to the open unit disk, you can compose the maps $f(z)=z^2$ and $g(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$, giving the desired map $h$, with $h(z) = \frac{z^2-i}{z^2+i}$, i.e. you first map the quadrant to the upper half plane and then the upper half plane to the unit disk.